# Access Denied randomly when connecting to mysql

Tags: spring, jsf, tomcat, jpa, eclipselink

I have a very rare problem it is a java web application with jsf 2.0, spring 3.0.3 and jpa2 eclipselink implementation running on tomcat 7 when deploying the application to server it run correctly without any errors and after random period of time it return Access Denied for user "user@host" and all i need to do is just restarting tomcat to work again.

Please help if you know anything about this problem.

Thanks,

Comment: What is returning this message?  What action specifically?  Is it an exception with a stack trace that you can post?  We need much more information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you leaking connections?

It sounds like you're using up all the connections and MySQL won't let you create new ones.